# Issue subtracting negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a recursive method to compute the sum of all odd numbers in the array. However, my program was adding negative numbers as positive numbers.

```
if(nums[start] % 2 == 1) {
  sum+=nums[start];
  return computeSumOfOdd(nums, start + 1, sum);
```

So I changed my code around to this:

```
if(nums[start] % 2 == 1) {
  if(nums[start] < 0)
    sum-=nums[start];
  else
    sum+=nums[start];
  return computeSumOfOdd(nums, start + 1, sum);
```

It still gives me the same response and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the type of `sum`? What is the type of `nums`, and what is its contents?

Comment: `num` is an `Integer[]`.
`sum` is an `int`.
`start` is an `int` representing the current index, which started at 0 at the beginning of the method

Comment: Java's `%` operator is not true modulo. `n%2` will never equal 1 for negative `n` -- consider `(n&1)` instead

Comment: How would `n%1` bypass that issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `x % 2` can never equal `1` for negative `x` (the only possible values for `x % 2` are `-1` and `0`).

Therefore, your two snippets are equivalent: the outer `if` statement is never entered when `nums[start] < 0`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3